# Using Org Babel to tangle to a variable file name

Tags: org-mode, org-babel

If I have a code snippet that I tangle to a file, but I expect the file name to change over time, Is there a cleaner way to change the filename than Query-replace?

For example, say I tangle code to ~/dir/my-file.el:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp :tangle ~/dir/my-file.el
(setq myvar1 "value1")
#+END_SRC

#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp :tangle ~/dir/my-file.el
(defun foo (bar) ... )
#+END_SRC

etc.
```

Then later on I realize that the file would be better placed in another location:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp :tangle ~/dir/my/file.el
(setq myvar1 "value1")
#+END_SRC

#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp :tangle ~/dir/my/file.el
(defun foo (bar) ... )
#+END_SRC

etc.
```

Is there a way to change the argument to :tangle dynamically.

I have investigated and discovered that I can feed elisp into the :tangle argument. If I evaluate `(setq myfile "~/dir/file.el)` and then tangle the following:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp :tangle (print myfile)
(setq myvar1 "value1")
#+END_SRC

#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp :tangle (print myfile)
(defun foo (bar) ... )
#+END_SRC
```

I get the desired result I am looking for.
I could then execute an elisp snippet to set the variable using org-babel, but I was wondering if there is a cleaner way to do so.

The docs on the :tangle header do not stipulate a native way.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You should not repeat such things, but define them in one place.
For example you can define output file in a [drawer](https://orgmode.org/manual/Drawers.html) as [header args](https://orgmode.org/manual/Header-arguments.html) for **whole tree and subtrees**:

```
* Header
:PROPERTIES:
:tangle: ~/dir/my/testfile.el
:END:
```

or for *:dir*

```
* Header
:PROPERTIES:
:header-args: :dir ~/dir/my/dir/
:END:
```

As described in [docs](https://orgmode.org/manual/Using-Header-Arguments.html#Using-header-arguments) you can have:

- System-wide header arguments
- Language-specific header arguments
- Header arguments in Org mode properties
- Language-specific header arguments in Org mode properties
- Code block specific header arguments
- Header arguments in function calls

Answer (score 7):

You can use a property of the org heading instead of a `setq`

```
* Header
:PROPERTIES:
:PRJ-DIR: ~/prj/dir/
:END:

#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp :tangle (concat (org-entry-get nil "PRJ-DIR" t) "file.el")
(setq myvar1 "value1")
#+END_SRC

#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp :tangle (concat (org-entry-get nil "PRJ-DIR" t) "file.el")
(defun foo (bar) ... )
#+END_SRC

etc.
```

This way you can set different file names for each source block.