# Org-mode Babel: Evaluating code in header of code block for tangling

Tags: org-babel

Is there a straightforward way to use a variable for the tangle file? For example, I want to tanlge my file into the directory `files`. For multiple files I could do

```
#+begin_src python :tangle files/fileA.py
some code
#+end_src

#+begin_src python :tangle files/fileB.py
some code
#+end_src
```

But that would mean repeating the file path every time. So ideally I would do something like

```
#+name: mydir
: files/

#+name: combine
#+begin_src python :var filename=""
return files+filename
#+end_src

#+begin_src python :tangle combine(fileA.py)
some code
#+end_src

#+begin_src python :tangle combine(fileB.py)
some code
#+end_src
```

But that doesn't work.

I tried using `:dir` instead but that doesn't work either, as it seems to apply to the execution directory, not the tangle directory.

I have found this [post](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/2328/using-org-babel-to-tangle-to-a-variable-file-name) that shows how to use **elisp variables** but that requires the use of `setq` and doesn't seem like a good idea.

Comment: Why don't you use the [solution of the post](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/2343/2370) you found. Especially, the `:header-args: :dir`  property should be a good choice for your case.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Maybe I'm misunderstanding something and the solution is plain simple. But `:dir` doesn't help since it only works on the output of the code block. Maybe I should rephrase my question to a more generic one: **How do you evaluate any kind of variables outside of code blocks?** So far I haven't been able to do that, neither for tangling, nor for using hyperlinks.

Comment: you can always use setq-local

Comment: Are you trying to to tangle the 3 blocks into a single file?

Comment: No, I'm trying to tangle every source block into its own file.