# Org-babel: Set root dir for tangled files

Tags: org-mode, org-babel

I have started using org-babel for a larger project, and have found [the readthedocs](https://org-babel.readthedocs.io) to be a great resource.  I have been using tangling to generate code from documentation, however setting the export filename using `:tangle` is gettting cumbersome, since for each block I need to set all of the relative paths and whatnot.

I know that setting the `:dir` header argument allows you to choose what directory code blocks will be executed in, but it does not set the tangle directory.  Ideally I would like to have something like this:

```
#+STARTUP: showall
#+PROPERTY: header-args :dir "/home/user/project/path1/path2/path3"

* Test

** myfile.h
:PROPERTIES:
:header-args: :tangle filename1.cpp :no-expand t
:END:
#+BEGIN_SRC C++

#+END_SRC
** myotherfile.cpp
:PROPERTIES:
:header-args: :tangle filename2.cpp :no-expand t
:END:
#+BEGIN_SRC C++

#+END_SRC
```

Rather than:

```
#+STARTUP: showall

* Test

** myfile.h
:PROPERTIES:
:header-args: :tangle ../../path2/path3 :no-expand t
:END:
#+BEGIN_SRC C++

#+END_SRC
** myotherfile.cpp
:PROPERTIES:
:header-args: :tangle ../../filename2.cpp :no-expand t
:END:
#+BEGIN_SRC C++

#+END_SRC
```

Imagine how frustrating this could get if another person takes over the project, or one needs to change the directory layout?  I have poked around various sources but haven't found a way to do this. [This question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/2328/using-org-babel-to-tangle-to-a-variable-file-name) is related, but doesn't solve my issue

Comment: I could be wrong but a quick perusal of the documentation and the `org-babel-tangle` code did not uncover a method for doing this. You may be able to do what you want with a function added to `org-babel-post-tangle-hook`. Or you can submit an RFE to the org-mode mailing list.

Comment: On second thought, submit an RFE: the post-tangle hook method gets very hairy very fast.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem and I solved by executing elisp code in tangle setting

```
* Project Header
:PROPERTIES:
:PRJ-DIR: ~/prj/dir/
:END:

#+BEGIN_SRC js :tangle (concat (org-entry-get nil "PRJ-DIR" t) "filename.js")
  var a = 2;
#+END_SRC
```