# Use property, name, or variable as part of header argument

Tags: org-mode, org-babel

I have a situation where I often want to run the same set of shell commands on different servers. Such a series of commands can look like:

```
#+begin_src bash :dir /ssh:purple:~/repo/
git pull --quiet origin master
git show | head -n 1
#+end_src

#+begin_src bash :dir /ssh:purple|su:root@purple:/
diff /sbin/thing /home/rovanion/repo/thing
#+end_src
```

I then want to repeat the same set of commands for a different machine, in a different org-file. Instead of running, and sometimes forgetting to run, search and replace for the hostname (purple) I would like to do something along these lines:

```
#+property: host purple

#+begin_src bash :dir /ssh:$host:~/repo/
git pull --quiet origin master
git show | head -n 1
#+end_src

#+begin_src bash :dir /ssh:$host|su:root@$host:/
diff /sbin/thing /home/rovanion/repo/thing
#+end_src
```

Where the property host can be defined per buffer. Is this possible?

Since I want to use different `:dir`'s for different parts of the command sequences just setting the header-argument `:dir` is not practical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer will get ya there: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/50767/24007

But define a property and get its value with `org-entry-get`. Something like this might be what you're looking for:

```
#+PROPERTY: me michael

#+BEGIN_SRC shell :dir (format "/home/%s" (org-entry-get nil "me" t))
echo $PWD
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
: /home/michael
```